# Reading files via SFTP in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Is it possible to read a file using SFTP in spark?

I tried using `val df = sc.textFile("sftp://user:password@host/home/user/sample.csv")`

But getting the below error

```
scala> df.count
java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: sftp
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2584)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2591)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:91)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2630)
```

Is there any way to read a file using sftp in spark?

Comment: Dunno. It'd be better to download it outside spark anyway because that way you won't have to hardcode your SFTP credentials into this job which is insecure and will make maintenance difficult. Once you've downloaded it outside spark, just pass the path into the job and load it as a normal text file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We've created a very simple spark SFTP connector to do that.

Here is the github link https://github.com/springml/spark-sftp

And it has been published to spark-packages as well. http://spark-packages.org/package/springml/spark-sftp

Comment: can we load the zip files from sftp directly. ie fileType supports Zip. Can you give me some insights in loading the zip files from sftp

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it is not possible at this moment (Spark 1.6, maximum profile hadoop-2.6). SFTP support will be introduced in Hadoop 2.8 (see [HADOOP-5732](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-5732)).

Comment: Now we can use spark-sftp connector to do that